# Connect to SVN from Windows Mobile

Tags: c#, .net, svn, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I have been trying to find a framework for windows mobile and .Net Compact to connect to an SVN Repository but i havnt been able to find 1.

1. Is there an SVN Framework out there for .NET Compact?
2. If there isnt a framework, whats the best way to attempt to connect to an SVN Repository? At the moment im looking to get the revision history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your just looking for revision history, you could setup a Apache server to do the SVN calls remotely and return it to Windows Mobile in some other readable format, such as XML.

The otherway would be to find a [WebDAV library](http://www.webdavsystem.com/) that works with .Net Compact to make calls to an Apache setup with WebDAV.

Comment: Yeh i thought that would be the case, i'd just rather have the mobile app connect to SVN directly...

Answer (score 0):

It would be some work to set up on your machine, but you could check whether [**Trac's timeline**](http://trac.edgewall.org/demo-0.12/timeline) works on your mobile client. In addition to the revision history, you can browse through the actual code and view diffs.

Trac is fully customizable to you can in theory create a template that is tailored to your mobile client, but in my experience it's not entirely trivial to do.